# EWS related query

Tags: exchangewebservices

One of my application uses EWS managed api to get exchange mail related data.

i would like to know following things.

1. EWS object once created by passing valid user credential; how does
   it validate subsequent request. Does sending subsequent request
   contains any kind of token or user credential based on that it gives
   requested data.
2. In addtion to above; if lets say initially EWS object created and then for 2-3 hours; if there are not any        ews request using api then if i make a EWS request will it be time out or i need to perform authenticatation again to exchange system.

Answer to above question will handle Exchange Service object properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. EWS Managed will either use NTLM or Basic auth if you using the standard credentials class (you can also use Oauth but I doubt that's the case). So depending how the server is configured you will have either the basic Auth header or the NTLM Auth Header included with each request. You can see this yourself using an App like fiddler to look at each of the request your app is making.
2. Not really an issue if its NTLM or Basic as the creds are sent with each request. But the easiest way for you to see this youreself is capture some requests and have a look.

Comment: thanks for your answer. is there any validity after that there will be timeout and need to create exchange object again.

Comment: No the only instance would maybe if somebody changed the password for the account.